# To delete a variable from req.body in NodeJS ExpressJS

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, express, request

I receive a JSON with lot of information but I want to delete a particular data, for example, if I receive the variable name, I want to remove this variable before adding my JSON in my Database. This is my function POST:

```
app.post("/:coleccion", function (req, res, next) {
POST
    if(req.body.name)
            // Here I need delete "name" if I receive this variable <------
    req.collection.insert(req.body, {}, function (e, result) {
        if(e) return next(e);
        res.send(result);
    });
});
```

Comment: does your destination collection have the attribute too?¿ if not, it should not be saved by default.

Comment: Yeah, but I want to know how I can remove an attribute

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to remove a property from a JavaScript object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/208105/how-to-remove-a-property-from-a-javascript-object)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
delete req.body.name
```

should work in a javascript object

check [How do I remove a property from a JavaScript object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/208105/how-to-remove-a-property-from-a-javascript-object)

Answer (score 5):

I would urge you to only pick the properties that you actually want instead of just removing the ones you don't. Otherwise the client could send in anything it wanted, including fields starting with `$` which will get special treatment by MongoDB.

This is the easiest way to do this:

```
var data = {
  email: req.body.email,
  age: req.body.age,
  gender: req.body.gender
}

req.collection.insert(data, ...)
```

You could also use [Underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/#pick) to do the job:

```
var data = _.pick(req.body, 'email', 'age', 'gender')

req.collection.insert(data, ...)
```